# How to measure latency of a python script

Tags: python, latency

I would like to measure the performances of my Rpi 3 while a program I made (in Python)is running on it. The program is getting data from the UART and is then supposed to launch a song or an image. Which way do I measure this time between a coming data and an output (here image or song as mentionned above) ... Thanks

Comment: Look into the `timeit` module https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 1):

One possible way:

```
import time
...
start = time.perf_counter()
# Your code that you want to time
end = time.perf_counter() - start
print('{:.6f}s for the calculation'.format(end))
```